# What does it mean for a complex function to have a period of 1?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a complex valued function $f$ has a period of $1$ does it mean that $f(z)=f(z+1)$ in the same sense as real functions? Moreover, if $f$ has lets say a period, that is not necessarily real say $w$, is it also the case that $f(z)=f(z+w)$?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. If you want you can post your comment as an answer so that I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for the remark. I have edited the question for clarity now.

Comment: In the complex, functions may have two distinct periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [encyclopedia of mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Periodic_function):

> A periodic function of a complex variable $z$ is a single-valued analytic function $f(z)$ having only isolated singular points (cf. Singular point) in the complex $z$- plane $\mathbf C$ and for which there exists a complex number $p\neq0$, called a period of the function $f(z)$, such that $$f(z+p)=f(z),\quad  z\in\mathbf C.$$